# Strip HTML formatting from contenteditable div but preserve line breaks on paste?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I currently have a content editable div which I use as an editor but I'm looking to strip html (not including `<br>` tags) on paste.

At the moment I have another div `<div class="hiddendiv common editor"></div>` this one which collects all text and data added to the `contenteditable` div in order to determine height of the contenteditable div.

I've become confused and unsure how I will do this.

My Question is: How do I strip html formatting (not including `<br>` tags) whilst inserting text at the cursor caret on paste with jQuery?

**HTML:**

```
<div contenteditable='true' id="textarea" class="editor plain-box large-box textarea text common text-content-input quicksand color-dark-grey" data-text="Start typing..."></div>

<div class="hiddendiv common editor"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
function pasteHtmlAtCaret(html) {
  var sel, range;
  if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
      range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
      range.deleteContents();
      var el = document.createElement("div");
      el.innerHTML = html;
      var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node, lastNode;
      while ((node = el.firstChild)) {
        lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
      }
      range.insertNode(frag);

      if (lastNode) {
        range = range.cloneRange();
        range.setStartAfter(lastNode);
        range.collapse(true);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
      }
    }
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(html);
  }
}

$('#textarea').on("paste", function() {
    var textarea = $('#textarea').html();
    var hidden_div = $('.hiddendiv').html(textarea);
    var plain_text = hidden_div.text();
    $('#textarea').pasteHtmlAtCaret(plain_text);
});

var txt = $('#textarea'),
    hiddenDiv = $(document.createElement('div')),
    content = null;

txt.addClass('txtstuff');
hiddenDiv.addClass('hiddendiv common editor');

$('body').append(hiddenDiv);

txt.on('keyup input propertychange', function () {

    content = $(this).html();

    content = content.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
    hiddenDiv.html(content + '<br>');

    $(this).css('height', hiddenDiv.height());

});
```

Comment: Why do you need a second DIV to determine height of the contenteditable div?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say it deals with adding <br> tags

Comment: It's not just `<br>` elements you need to worry about, it's also line breaks implied by block elements such as `<p>` and `<div>`.

Answer (score -1):

This may be what you’re looking for:

```
<div contenteditable="plaintext-only" id="textarea" data-text="Start typing..."></div>
```